# Call a method on click on a node on cytoscape graph

Tags: cytoscape.js, cytoscape, cytoscape-web

I am trying to call a method by passing in the id of the node but it keeps saying that method is not a function.

Here is the stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/cytoscape-call-method?file=src/app/app.component.ts

You can click on any node and see the console error. It says this.showId is not a function.

Some code

```
 this.cy.on('click', 'node', function(evt) {
      console.log('clicked ' + this.id());
      this.showId(this.id());
    });
```

I have tried using tap as well but it still gives the same error.

Comment: try `evt.target.id()`

Comment: You should read up on cytoscape.js [events](https://js.cytoscape.org/#events). The comment above works just fine, you don't need a function (showId) for that.

Comment: @StephanT. That is just an example. I want to pass the id and call a service to get more data. The issue is that event does not recognize the function in the class. It has to be outside the class which means all the services are not available outside that class

Comment: @canbax The issue is not getting the id, it is about calling a method like I mentioned. That is just an example, I need the id to call something else or call a service which is injected in the constructor of the class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm I think I see what you mean. It's about scopes in JS. Try below

```
this.cy.on('click', 'node', (evt) => {
  console.log('clicked ' + this.id());
  this.showId(this.id());
});
```

or below

```
this.cy.on('click', 'node', function (evt) {
  console.log('clicked ' + this.id());
  this.showId(this.id());
}.bind(this));
```

Both are actually the same

Comment: 2nd one works for me. It saves my life.